# JSON encoding details

Tags: json, encoding, language-specifications

I was reading JSON's succinct [language specification](http://json.org/) and got surprised for this sentence:

*Excepting a few encoding details, that completely describes the language.*

What are the details which can break those simple rules.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [RFC 4627](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc4627.txt) for the full specification. Specifically related to encoding:

> JSON text SHALL be encoded in Unicode.  The default encoding is
>      UTF-8.

If your text isn't Unicode, it isn't JSON.

Comment: Nitpick: That RFC is not a spec. It says: _"This memo provides information for the Internet community.  It does not specify an Internet standard of any kind."_

Comment: Rather, see [ECMA-404 The JSON Data Interchange Standard](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST/ECMA-404.pdf) (linked from json.org)